# Angular remove content of style tag in head

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, head

I use Angular 13. Angular does not display the content of the [style tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78IOz.png) in head, although it is present in the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78IOz.png). The content of the tag is not important, neither is the total number of tags. The middle tag always shows no content.

Maybe someone encountered such a bug and knows the reason?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular strips out style and script tags from the component templates for security purposes. If you need to load styles from an external source, the default security can be bypassed.
Here's an article that should point you in the right direction: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90

Comment: I heard about this, but the problem is not in this, angular, for some unknown reason, removes the contents of one tag.